# Partial Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a SQL table of the following format

```
    Date                        Process1                     Process2               ...
2017-04-10 00:00:00.0000000 2017-04-11 02:49:10.0000000 2017-04-11 04:08:10.0000000 ...
2017-04-11 00:00:00.0000000 2017-04-12 02:55:09.0000000 NULL                        ...
```

I want to pivot the table in the following format

```
            Date                ProcessName     ProcessTime
2017-04-10 00:00:00.0000000     Process1        2017-04-11 02:49:10.0000000
2017-04-10 00:00:00.0000000     Process2        2017-04-11 04:08:10.0000000
2017-04-11 00:00:00.0000000     Process1        2017-04-12 02:55:09.0000000
2017-04-11 00:00:00.0000000     Process2        NULL
```

Could someone please help me out as to how can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is call UNPIVOT not PIVOT

```
select  *
from    yourtable
        unpivot
        (
             ProcessTime for ProcessName in (Process1, Process2)
        ) u
```

Please also refer to [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Alternatively, you can do it using `UNION ALL`

```
select  Date, ProcesTime = Process1, ProcessName = 'Process1' from yourtable union all
select  Date, ProcesTime = Process2, ProcessName = 'Process2' from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNPIVOT method :

```
 CREATE TABLE #table1 ( Date DATETIME, Process1 DATETIME , Process2 
            DATETIME) 

 INSERT INTO #table1 ( Date , Process1 , Process2 )
 SELECT '2017-04-10 00:00:00','2017-04-11 02:49:10','2017-04-11 04:08:10' 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT '2017-04-11 00:00:00','2017-04-12 02:55:09',NULL

 SELECT Date,ProcessName,ProcessTime
 FROM 
 (
   SELECT  Date , Process1 , Process2  
   FROM #table1
 ) A
 UNPIVOT 
 (
   ProcessTime  FOR ProcessName IN (Process1 ,  Process2)
 ) UnPvt
```